# MSE Loss is reducing with a very small amount during training pytorch

Tags: performance, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function, mse

I'm trying out my first deep learning program for speech separation using ideal ratio mask. It is a BLSTM model. The mse loss obtained while training is reducing with a very small quantity. Any idea about why it is happening and how to fix it?? thank you
my learning rate is 0.0003, adam optimizer, batch size 64, training dataset 3000 files and validation dataset is 340 files. I tried changing the learning rate and tried learning rate decay as well. still getting the same problem. I've been stuck here for a long time. Please do help. Thank you

```
Train Epoch: 1 Loss: 0.027980 
  val Epoch: 1  Loss: 0.025925
Train Epoch: 2 Loss: 0.027975 
  val Epoch: 2  Loss: 0.025961
Train Epoch: 3 Loss: 0.027973 
  val Epoch: 3  Loss: 0.025987
```

here is my model

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

print("Is the GPU available:", torch.cuda.is_available())  # True
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Base_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base_model, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=322, hidden_size=300, num_layers=4, bidirectional = True, batch_first=True)
        self.rel = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=600, out_features=161)
        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid()
        
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # print(x.size(0))

        out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        out = self.fc(out)
        out = self.activation(out)
        return out
```

my training code

```
start_epoch = 0
    if args.model_name:
        print("Load the model:", args.checkpoints_dir + args.model_name)
        checkpoint = torch.load(args.checkpoints_dir + args.model_name)
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["model"])
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint["optimizer"])
        start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
        # lr_schedule.load_state_dict(checkpoint['lr_schedule'])  # load lr_scheduler

    for epoch in range(start_epoch, args.epochs):
        model.train()  # train model
        for batch_idx, (train_X, train_mask, train_nearend_mic_magnitude, train_nearend_magnitude) in enumerate(
                train_loader):
            train_X = torch.reshape(train_X, (train_X.shape[0],train_X.shape[2],train_X.shape[1]))
            train_mask = torch.reshape(train_mask, (train_mask.shape[0],train_mask.shape[2],train_mask.shape[1]))
            train_nearend_mic_magnitude = torch.reshape(train_nearend_mic_magnitude, (train_nearend_mic_magnitude.shape[0],train_nearend_mic_magnitude.shape[2],train_nearend_mic_magnitude.shape[1]))
            train_nearend_magnitude = torch.reshape(train_nearend_magnitude, (train_nearend_magnitude.shape[0],train_nearend_magnitude.shape[2],train_nearend_magnitude.shape[1]))
            
            train_X = train_X.to(device) 
            train_mask = train_mask.to(device)  # IRM [batch_size 161, 999]
            train_nearend_mic_magnitude = train_nearend_mic_magnitude.to(device)
            train_nearend_magnitude = train_nearend_magnitude.to(device)

            # forward propagation
            optimizer.zero_grad()  # zero out the gradient
            pred_mask = model(train_X)  # [batch_size, 322, 999]--> [batch_size, 161, 999]
            train_loss = criterion(pred_mask, train_mask)
            
            # backpropagation
            train_loss.backward()  # backpropagation
            optimizer.step()  # update parameters

            # ###########    Visual printing   ############
        print('Train Epoch: {} Loss: {:.6f} '.format(epoch + 1, train_loss.item()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest u use a bigger learning rate and make a decaying learning rate:

torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR.html

Comment: hi @Shoval Eliezer I did try with a larger learning rate and still the same. When i tested out my model it doesn't not give the output i need.